# (sqlite3) Is it possible to SELECT based on cascade/recursive condition?

Tags: database, select, sqlite

Let's say I have this table:

```
Parent         ID         FileName                 Flag
0              1          C:\                      -1
1              2          C:\Test\                 0
2              3          C:\Test\Test2\           0
3              4          C:\Test\Test2\file.txt   0
0              5          D:\                      0
5              6          D:\file-2.txt            0
```

I'd like to select records that satisfy these 2 conditions:

1. Flag <> -1
2. None of the parent records have Flag <> -1

Is this possible in sqlite3? ie.

`SELECT FileName FROM MyTable WHERE Flag <> -1 And Recursive(Parent) <> -1`

So that in the example table, a query like this would return `D:\file-2.txt`, but **not** `C:\Test\Test2\file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have any mechanism that could do recursive lookups over arbitrary depths.
You would have to implement this logic in whatever language you are accessing the database from.

In this particular example, you could try to look up based on the file name:

```
SELECT FileName
FROM MyTable A
WHERE Flag <> -1
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID
                  FROM MyTable B
                  WHERE SUBSTR(B.FileName, -1) = '\'
                    AND A.FileName LIKE B.FileName || '%'
                    AND B.Flag = -1)
```